# Get Data When More Objects in one json file with same strings

Tags: javascript, json, api

I want F1 API to check for the leaderboard (link below). I want to get every players info and then document.write there info in json format. i dont know how because there are multiple strings the same so could someone please tell me how.

https://ergast.com/api/f1/2008/5/driverStandings.json

for the api recommened is downloading a json formatter

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: Parse the JSON string into an object using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: i shared the link from the api with the exact text